# Retaking sms in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, sms

I'd like to know if it is possible to retake sms from specific number in iOS app. I need to have a way to do it on jailbroken and not phones. I need the app to retake sms completely - without showing notification or appearing in messages. I do not need to be able to send sms from the phone, nor to read other, just to catch sms from specific number and display the information from sms in my app. That was already done in android and now it needs to get working on iOS. If it is not possible with current apis maybe you could advice me some different ways how to get such idea working?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Sms come from home security system chip, so app is to handle your security system via telephone, get status, change status and so on.

Comment: How about doing it the right way... i.e. using push notifications?

Comment: Security system has gsm module, not internet. So it can only recieve and send sms messages or call...

Comment: Then you need to build a proxy that receives those sms messages.

Comment: I don't think so. And keep in mind that no code is run automatically on the device even for push notifications. The use has to open the app.

Comment: This is no malicious software. You may ask the user for permission to send and receive messages from certain number, or even the user could input the exact number and the app could work only with that number,  if only such thing would help to get it into AppStore. Because building server to receive and send messages would take up some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this on iOS with the official SDK.

Comment: And by using unofficial frameworks will I be able to post the app to app store? In any case, how should i do this, there must be a solution

Comment: No, your app will be rejected since it's not allowed by apple.

Comment: There is no way you will get that on the AppStore - and I'm very happy about that.